# Why List<?> can convert to List<E> through method invocation conversion?

Tags: java

----------- lasted update ---------

I think maybe `List<?>` and `List<E>` are the same type when we declare them as a method argument. I tried to convert `List<E>` to `List<?>`, it worked fine too:

```java
public static <E> void swap2(List<E> list, int i, int j){
    swapHelper2(list, i ,j);
}

private static void swapHelper2(List<?> list, int i, int j) {
    ...
}
```

------------ original question ------------

From 《Effective Java》 Item 31 it says:

> The idea is to write a private helper method to capture the wildcard type...

'private helper method':

```java
public static void swap(List<?> list, int i, int j) {
    swapHelper(list, i, j);
}
// Private helper method for wildcard capture
private static <E> void swapHelper(List<E> list, int i, int j) { 
    list.set(i, list.set(j, list.get(i)));
}
```

My question is why List<?> could convert to List<E> through method invocation without compile error?

In my opinion I think List<?> is a SuperType of any List<E>, so it should need some narrowing conversion such as:

```java
List<?> list = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> listOfString = (List<String>)list;
swapHelper(listOfString, 0 ,0);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why are Java generics not implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po)

Comment: `swapHelper` works with lists of any type. `swap` takes a list of *some specific but unspecified* type, which falls under the remit of "any".

Comment: Can you think of a single argument you could pass to `swap` which you would not want to be allowed to be passed along to `swapHelper`? If you answered no, that's why this is not a compiler error.

Comment: @Alays  I don't think they are the same.
In brief,  `List<Dog> Question` is about what's the difference between List<Child> and List<Parent>? and why java can't treat List<Child> as a subtype of List<Parent>.
My question is what's the difference between List<?> and List<E>?In method invocation conversion why List<?> can convert to List<E> without transforming its type to List<E>,  but in variable assignment conversion context(as the example above),we need (List<String>) to avoid compile error.

Comment: @Michael I partly agree with you. But I think maybe `List<?>` and `List<E>` are the same types when we declare them as method arguments, because I tried convert List<E> to List<?>, it worked too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What does `List<?>` really represents? It means "a list containing some *unknown* type of objects".

What does a method say when it has a type argument `<E>` as your `swapHelper`? It says: I accept *any arbitrary type E*.

We know that the `?` above is a some type, we just don't know which one. The `<E>` accepts *any* type, so we know that *whatever `?` represents it can be used as `E`*. That's why you can call `swapHelper` with a `List<?>`.

Why can't we do that trick by simply assigning a `List<?>` variable to a `List<E>` variable? Because a local variable *doesn't have type arguments*, those only exist on methods and classes.

So the fact that `swapHelper` has the unrestricted type variable makes it able to accept a `List<?>` without anything in the code ever "knowing" what the `?` really represents, since it only cares that there *is* a type, not *what* that type is.

Comment: Actual question on your answer: why not declare `swap` as taking a type of `List<E>`?  In this case wouldn't that accomplish the same thing as `List<?>` as well as being a type that could be swapped directly?  Maybe there's some reason, I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: Yes, `swap` could equally just be declared as having a type argument and accepting a `List<E>`. But that would hide the very relevant fact, that even a `List<?>` can be referenced as a `List<E>` under the right circumstances. A `List<?>` is not a "one-way street". Basically an unrestricted type argument like on `swapHelper` works very similarly to a wildcard type declaration. The small, but important difference is that with the type argument you can actually refer to and use the type `E` in your code (implicitly or explicitly)

Comment: Got it, thanks for the pedagogical answer.

Comment: @markspace ref from 《Effective Java》
>  In a public API, the second(`public static void swap(List<?> list, int i, int j)`) is better because it’s simpler.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`List<?>` means "a List whose element type isn't known **here**".

That's not to say that the element type isn't known at all, just, at this point in the code, you don't know what it is.

But all `List`s have *some* element type (unless they are raw, I suppose). So, a `List<?>` has *some* element type, if only you knew what it was.

When you say `List<E>`, you still don't really know what the type of the element is. You know that it's a subtype of `Object`, but nothing more than that. However, significantly, you know that if you get an element out of a `List<E>`, then it's a thing of type `E`:

```
E item = list.get(i);
```

and you know that it would be safe to put that thing back into the list:

```
list.set(j, item);
```

You don't know what type `E` is - but you do know that it's the same type as the elements in the list.

So, you can always pass a `List<?>` to a generic *method* (that is, it declares its own type variables) that expects a `List<E>`, because you're saying that the elements have a consistent type, even if you don't know what it is.